# Running an external Javascript script on two ASP.NET update panels

Tags: javascript

So I am running a external file that basically counts characters in a textbox as a person types. When I use a single update panel and do the BindEvents thing no issues. But 2 update panel rebinds every time and creates duplicate returns. I know the problem but my limited Javascript skills prevent me from fixing it. I thought maybe someone with more skills has the answer.

Here is the link to the actual external JS file I am using.

https://github.com/EspadaV8/jqEasyCharCounter-Extended

Appreciate anything anyone can suggest. Thank you.

```
    function BindEvents() {







        $(document).ready(function () {

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

            function EndRequest(sender, args) {
                alert(sender._postBackSettings.panelID + " -> " + sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id);
            }



            $('.10textbox').jqEasyCounter({
                'maxChars': 10,
                'maxCharsWarning': 8,
                'msgFontSize': '12px',
                'msgFontColor': '#000000',
                'msgFontFamily': 'Arial',
                'msgTextAlign': 'left',
                'msgWarningColor': '#FF3300',
                'msgAppendMethod': 'insertBefore'
            });

            $('.10textbox2').jqEasyCounter({
                'maxChars': 10,
                'maxCharsWarning': 8,
                'msgFontSize': '12px',
                'msgFontColor': '#000000',
                'msgFontFamily': 'Arial',
                'msgTextAlign': 'left',
                'msgWarningColor': '#FF3300',
                'msgAppendMethod': 'insertBefore'
            });

        });
    }



</script>
```

```
<%--**********************************************************************************************************************************--%>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
        </script>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="10textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<%--**********************************************************************************************************************************--%>

<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
        </script>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="10textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<%--**********************************************************************************************************************************--%>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Could you try to reduce your code to a [mcve]?

Comment: The code I posted reproduces it exactly. The only thing you need to add would be the external JS file which I have supplied a link to. Cheers

Comment: Yes, but it seems not to be minimal.